# Basic script in C (String display)

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple script on my server, basically I would like to sent a string and display it via system function...

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char txt[100];
    printf("Insert a text: ");
    fgets(txt, 100, stdin);
    system("echo %s"), txt;
    return 0;
}
```

Rght now I'm not getting any string just "%s"

any idea why?

Comment: First, the line with `system` thing is totally not what you intend to do. Use `printf`, or at least correct `system` syntax. Second, you should look up for **script** definition and how it is different from C program.

Comment: I have to use "system" because I would like to run some commands in linux but to do this I need to sent string to command

Comment: `system` with `echo` will print to `stdout`. `printf` will print to stdout. So what is the difference?

Comment: @Matt, Then form a string that includes the command and parameters and give that to `system` or use an API designed for starting processes. By the way, Clang warns about the `system` line because `txt` is evaluated and then not used.

Comment: "*script*" is there a C (or even C++) interpreter around?

Comment: You're echoing %s, so that's what you're seeing.

Comment: construct a string with complete command. str = "echo value_of_text". then system(str)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881937/building-strings-from-variables-in-c

Comment: @alk Yes, there are. Some examples listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers

Comment: Please do not tag spam, this is c not c++

Answer (score 4):

```
system("echo %s"), txt;
```

This isn't doing what you think; it's an expression which evaluates to `txt`. Since evaluating `txt` has no side effects, and since you're not capturing the result of the expression anywhere, adding `, txt` after the `system` call essentially does nothing. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) for some information on the "comma"-operator in C.

Moreover, `system` doesn't support the use of `printf`-style format specifiers, so the `%s` in your string literal doesn't have any special meaning; it's just going to be echoed exactly as written, as you've seen. If you want to construct a command at runtime for use with `system`, you will have to do so with `sprintf` or similar.

Comment: 1+ for explaining what really happens.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype to `system()` is:

```
int system(const char * command);
```

From [`man 3 system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> executes the shell command specified in *command*

From this we can safely assume `s` refers to a C-"string".

So prepare the string using for example [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

```
char s[1024];
snprintf(s, 1024 -1, "echo %s", txt); /* -1 for the C-"string"'s 0-terminator */
```

Then pass it:

```
system(s);
```

Comment: Quick question, can I get string from a command line and display it in snprintf so txt will be replaced with a text from command line?

Comment: @Matt: Use `int main(int argc, char ** argv)` to access what had been given as parameters to the program on start-up via `argc` and `argv`. Details on this however would better go into another question you might like to pose.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `system("echo %s"), txt;` try this:

```
printf("%s", txt);
```

Comment: Irrelevant to op's problem

Comment: @Mekap Why? Did you read `Rght now I'm not getting any string just "%s"` ?

Comment: @deviantfan He's willing to execute a script (ie a shell function) who will print a line. He doesn't want or need to use printf. Read the question more carefully before making any wrong asumptions.

Answer (score 0):

the system statement will not format the output, like printf.

suggest using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // system()
#include <string.h> // strcpy(), strcat()

#define BUF_LEN (100)

int main()
{
    char output[10+BUF_LEN] = "echo ";
    char txt[BUF_LEN] = {'\0'};
    printf("Insert a text: ");
    fgets(txt, BUF_LEN, stdin);
    strcat( output, txt );
    system( output );
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works very nicely, however;

do not include any command separators, semicolons, or other characters that would be interpreted by the shell in the input string.

Comment: Why `+10` when `+5` would do?

Comment: What about if I will need to put string in the middle? for example echo [my string] >> text.txt ?

Comment: +10 .vs.+5?  a little extra room never hurts.  If the scenario has the input text in the middle, then there will need to be an extra strcat() and the initial string will need to be appropriately longer. (and probably there will need to be " surrounding the input text.